# Should I use a callback when using an async queue?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I'm using async.js' `queue`, and I'm not sure if I should process each task one at a time or not. The task itself is a simple and quick message sent to a socket.

```
process: (task, done) ->
  task.client.send(task.model, done)
```

vs

```
process: (task, done) ->
  task.client.send(task.model)
  done()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct answer is "it depends".

The `done` callback must be called inside the task function when the task is complete to inform the queue of its conclusion.

The `task.client.send` is an async operation, so it will be completed in a near future. For this reason there is a callback as second argument that can be used by the caller to know when the send operation is completed.

If, for you, the task is completed when the send request is ended, you should pass the `done` callback to `task.client.send` as in:

```
process: (task, done) ->
    task.client.send(task.model, done)
```

If, for you, the task is completed when the send operation is started, you should call it after `task.client.send` as in:

```
process: (task, done) ->
    task.client.send(task.model)
    done()
```

In this case, the task can be considered completed before the send operation is concluded.

The drawback I see in the second case (the one with the `done` call after the `send` call) is that you have not a control over the concurrency of the `send` calls. The default level of concurrency for the Async.js `queue` method is `1`, so in the second case a `send` call is executed before the previous one is terminated. For this reason, all the `send` requests can be started simultaneously and you cannot limit them.

In the first case (the `done` as second argument of `send`) you have a better control over `send` request and can control the level of parallelism using the `queue` second argument (`concurrency`).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, but it doesn't really tell me anything I don't already know. I'm aware of how callbacks work, my question in this context would then be when should I consider the task to be done? Could I just asynchronously send many, or would it be better to send them one at a time, ie. wait for the callback before sending the next one?

Comment: @paranoid-android you really need to provide more info before anyone can answer that question for you.

Comment: Just edited the answer, trying to better answer your doubt... Let me know what do you think...